# Peroxide bleaching for bast fibres?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, color

Is peroxide bleaching ($\ce{H2O2}$) suitable for treating bast fibres? I read that to be successful, it needs to be combined with chlorine bleaching. Because of the end usage, I don't want to use this kind of bleaching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old patents of the 1930s, particularly from I.G. Farben often describe the use of hypochlorite/chlorine in the bleaching of bast.

However, from newer literature, such as this application manual for hydrogen peroxide bleaching from [Evonik Industries](http://h2o2.evonik.com/sites/dc/Downloadcenter/Evonik/Product/H2O2/applications---hydrogen-peroxide-for-textile-industry.pdf), I would conclude that bleaching of bast can be performed **without** chlorine, supposed that the peroxide bleaching is performed

- in alkaline medium
- at elevated temperatures $(85-90\,°\mathrm{C})$